# Error in selecting part of the xml document using linq

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml

Hi this is my xml file. I want to select the level4 module's modulecode, moduletiltle and credits, but when i used Descendants node it will showed me all descendant nodes for all levels. but i want the linq query for selection only level4 module information

```
<myCourse>
  <courseName>BEng Mobile and Web Computing</courseName>
  <courseStructure>
    <level4>
      <module>
        <moduleCode>ECSC401</moduleCode>
        <moduleTitle>Programming Methodology</moduleTitle>
        <credits>15</credits>
        <semester>1</semester>
      </module>
      <module>
        <moduleCode>ECSC404</moduleCode>
        <moduleTitle>Computer Systems Fundamentals</moduleTitle>
        <credits>15</credits>
        <semester>1</semester>
      </module>
    </level4>
    <level5>
      <module>
        <moduleCode>ECSE501</moduleCode>
        <moduleTitle>Object Oriented Development</moduleTitle>
        <credits>30</credits>
        <semester>0</semester>
      </module>
      <module>
        <moduleCode>ECWM506</moduleCode>
        <moduleTitle>Mobile Computing Principles</moduleTitle>
        <credits>15</credits>
        <semester>1</semester>
      </module>
    </level5>
  </courseStructure>
</myCourse>
```

My code to select level4 descendants:

```
var query = from r in xmlDoc.Element("level4").Descendants("module")
            select new
            {
                moduleCode=r.Element("moduleCode").Value,
                moduleTitle = r.Element("moduleTitle").Value,
                credits = r.Element("credits").Value
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be grabbing only the descendant `module` nodes of `level4` as intended. One issue with your query is that it should walk the XML tree rather than start at `level4` the way you have it written. In other words, there should be a reference to `courseStructure` in your query.

Try this:

```
var level4 = xdoc.Element("courseStructure")
                 .Element("level4");
var query = from r in level4.Descendants("module")
            select new
            {
                moduleCode = r.Element("moduleCode").Value,
                moduleTitle = r.Element("moduleTitle").Value,
                credits = r.Element("credits").Value
            };
```

Of course you can replace the `level4` variable and string them all together but for clarity I've broken it apart.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply,it Worked fine.I declared xdoc as Xdocument but It should be XElement type.When I changed that to XElement I  got the desire result. Thanks Mageed.

Comment: One Question could you please tell me what is the differnet between XElement and the XDocument based on the selection query in Linq,because I'm using linq recently.

Comment: @XAr an `XDocument` represents an entire XML Document with associated metadata, while an `XElement` represents an XML fragment. You can usually get away with using either one, but you'll need to be aware of the querying differences: [Querying an XDocument vs. Querying an XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx). For an `XDocument` your query would've worked with `xdoc.Root.Element(...)` - notice the `Root` property.